# VBA: excel is closing, no error generated

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which I run on many file. The goal is to define a source and copy the value inside my file. It works fine for 30 source files but I recently have one that makes my excel crash, no error message nothing.

Here the code:

```
'dimensioning of the variables
'range and workbook
Dim Target_Area As Range
Dim Account_Number, Account_Description, Debit, Credit As Range
Dim General_Balance As Workbook
Dim Transform_file As Workbook
Dim Source_Range As Range

'technical var
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellNumber As Long
Dim Array_Position As Integer
Dim Worksheet_general_balance As Long
Dim Links As Variant
Dim address As String

'var used to adapt to the different trial balance
Dim startline, account_column, description_column, debit_column, credit_column As Integer
Dim column_to_test As String
Dim Target_Column(0 To 3) As Integer

'setting the variables
address = "blabla"
startline = 5
account_column = 1
description_column = 2
debit_column = 3
credit_column = 4
column_to_test = "A"
Target_Column(0) = 1 
Target_Column(1) = 4 
Target_Column(2) = 5 
Target_Column(3) = 6 
Worksheet_general_balance = 1 

Set Transform_file = ActiveWorkbook
Set General_Balance = Workbooks.Open(address)

With General_Balance.Worksheets(Worksheet_general_balance)
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, column_to_test).End(xlUp)
    LastCellNumber = LastCell.Row

End With

MsgBox "General TB sheet name: " & General_Balance.Worksheets(Worksheet_general_balance).Name

'3. save the required range from the source file
General_Balance.Worksheets(Worksheet_general_balance).Activate
Set Account_Number = General_Balance.Worksheets(Worksheet_general_balance).Range(Cells(startline, account_column), Cells(LastCellNumber, account_column))
Set Account_Description = General_Balance.Worksheets(Worksheet_general_balance).Range(Cells(startline, description_column), Cells(LastCellNumber, description_column))
Set Debit = General_Balance.Worksheets(Worksheet_general_balance).Range(Cells(startline, debit_column), Cells(LastCellNumber, debit_column))
Set Credit = General_Balance.Worksheets(Worksheet_general_balance).Range(Cells(startline, credit_column), Cells(LastCellNumber, credit_column))

'copying the value to the file
Transform_file.Activate
Transform_file.Worksheets("general balance").Range(Cells(6, Target_Column(0)), Cells(LastCellNumber - startline + 6, Target_Column(0))).Value = Account_Number.Value
Transform_file.Worksheets("general balance").Range(Cells(6, Target_Column(1)), Cells(LastCellNumber - startline + 6, Target_Column(1))).Value = Account_Description.Value

'up to this point, everything works well


'THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES EITHER ONE OF THEM MAKE EXCEL CRASH
Transform_file.Worksheets("general balance").Range(Cells(6, Target_Column(2)), Cells(LastCellNumber - startline + 6, Target_Column(2))).Value = Debit.Value
Transform_file.Worksheets("general balance").Range(Cells(6, Target_Column(3)), Cells(LastCellNumber - startline + 6, Target_Column(3))).Value = Credit.Value



 General_Balance.Close
```

If I replace the range name Debit or Credit by Account_Number for example, the macro will finish, so i guess it's not about the destination.

I tried to put this code:

```
For Each cell In Debit.Cells

MsgBox cell.Value

Next cell
```

Before the problematic lines, and it goes through all the cells without any problems.

I can't find any reason why it's not working... any idea ?

Comment: Just a quick glance observation, but your Dim statement where `Debit` is declared might not be doing what you think it's doing... `Debit` is not explicitly assigned, so it is currently a `Variant`. Use this to ensure that line is all `Range` variables: `Dim Account_Number As Range, Account_Description As Range, Debit As Range, Credit As Range`

Comment: good to know. I changed it however it wasn't causing my problem

Comment: Did you try to step through the code one line at a time?

Comment: which are the "problematic lines" that you mention?

Comment: Try debug.print on all the variables before the 2 lines that crash

Comment: @Siddarth I believe I don't need too as I have identified the code that makes excel crash, it's in my comments. Alex I did not know this function I'll try

Comment: You can always add error handling to your code... That should prevent it from crashing.

Comment: I have error handling

Comment: What do you mean by "makes my excel crash, no error message nothing"?  How do you know the fault is with one of the statements identified in your comment?  Where is `Target_Column` defined?

Comment: @TonyDallimore I mean it's excel that crashes, not the visual basic hat shows me a bug: that's why error handling and error description are useless. I added how I define Target_Column. How did I identified these lines ? the old way, I commented every instruction until I found the one ;)

Comment: I have experienced something that might be related although its effect was different.  Like you I was consolidating lots of workbooks into one although my work was apparently successful. I then realised that only part of some workbooks was being consolidated. I eventually tracked it down to a bulk transfer of data causing an immediate exit from a macro. My macro was several levels down so the calling macro carried on. Since yours in a top level macro perhaps the same problem is closing Excel. What I discovered was certain values cannot be transferred as part of a bulk transfer. ...

Comment: For example, I know you can bulk transfer strings of 900 characters but not of 1,000 characters but there may be other problem values. Look for anything about the data in the problem workbooks that looks different. If that does not reveal a possible cause, try selectively clearing data. If your problem is related to mine you will find a value that cannot be copied as part of a bulk transfer. My solution was to remove the suspect data before the bulk transfer, copy everything else and then copy the suspect values individually. Single cell copies did not seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should add some `On Error` to your code, including a
`MsgBox Err.Description,,Err.Number`.
My first guess is that you are trying to write to an already open/locked file.

```
    Sub test()
        On Error GoTo Hell
        'Do lots of things
        '...
    Adios:
        Exit Sub

    Hell:
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & Err.Number
        Resume Adios
        Resume

    End Sub
```

With the above sample, when you get the message box, press Ctrl+Break, move the yellow dot from the `resume Adios` to the `Resume` line, then press F8. Now you are on the line that caused the error.

Another way is to start your `Sub` in debug mode, and press F8 until it crashes (and remember where that was !).